# How to call javascript after frame is fully rendered?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am looking for a way to modify an `iFrame` attribute (a textbox value actually). The `iFrame` is on another domain and I do have access to it. From what I understand I must do that after the entire page (`iFrame` included) is rendered. I tryed something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    alert("test");
    d = document.getElementById("myframe");
    d.contentWindow.document.getElementById("frametxtbox");
});
</script>
```

But I always get the following error:

> Cannot call method 'getElementById' of undefined

I also noticed that the alert pops up BEFORE the `iFrame` is rendered, so I think my script is executed before page has access to frame values and, therefore I get the error. I have very few knowledge of web-related programming (always worked on backend side) so forgive me if my question maybe makes no sense.

Comment: `contentWindow` is not a document. IIRC you want `contentWindow.document`

Comment: Tried that as well, still same error.

Comment: Do you have access to the document which loads within the iframe?

Comment: @Kaf Well I have to be honest, I don't know what you guys mean with "access". Are you talking about permissions? Domain access? What do you mean? From what I know it looks like I do have access but I repeat it depends on what you mean. I am not an expert on that.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is can you change that document which loads into your iframe?

Comment: Just so you know the two documents reside on the same intranet, maybe it can help.

Comment: @Kaf No unfortunately I can't :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the iframe points to another domain, it'll be subject to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). This means that before you try to access its document you'll have to check the wiki and relax the policy (check the link for details). After that you'll need to bind ready event to the iframes document, rather than your main page doc.

```
$(window.frames['myframe'].document).ready(function() { alert('moo'); });
```

See if this helps :)